# how to check is the checkbox checked in WPF Prism

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a UserControlButtons.Xaml in this there is checkbox and button Save. when the save is clicked and if checkbox is checked then open a popup.Save is always enabled.

```
          <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox1" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Content="Add To Time Sheet" FontSize="14" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="2,2,2,2"
             IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=UserControlButtons, Path=UserControlButtonsBL .IsCheckedComplete,Mode=TwoWay}"
```

In the UserControlButtonsViewModel DelegateCommand Save has  CanSave and Save

In the BL Module there is UserControlButtonsBL here i declared the property for checkbox

```
     private bool _isCheckedComplete;
     public bool IsCheckedComplete
     {
         get { return _isCheckedComplete; }
         set
         {
             _isCheckedComplete = value;

         }
     }
```

in the code behind i added the dependency property

```
    public UserControlButtonsBL UserControlButtonsBL 
    {
        get
        {
            return (UserControlButtonsBL )GetValue(UserControlButtonsBLProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(UserControlButtonsBLProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

here even when i checked the checkbox IsCheckedComplete giving me false

Comment: What is your user controls datacontext if it is set to the UserControllButtonBL then your bindig should be {Binding IsChechedComplete, Mode=TwoWay}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here in the checkbox you should make the binding Mode two way and also set the update source trigger to `PropertyChanged`

```
           <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox1" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Content="Add To Time Sheet" FontSize="14" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="2,2,2,2"
         IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=UserControlButtons, Path=UserControlButtonsBL .IsCheckedComplete,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

here i am assuming that you have set your DataContext Correctly.... if you check box is in UserControl which has a `DataContext` as `myDataCntext` then binding path will be Directly the property ie IsChecked